# How to optimize insert rate in Oracle DB when the record count is high and some columns indexed?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am having a Java program which reads data from file and writes into a table. The table has 4 columns indexed and it has around 1000 million records in it. Now my program inserts records very slowly. Before it was taking 5 mins to process a file. But now it is taking about more than 30 mins.

Please guide me on this. I am using Batch update in JDBC.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: First of all you have turn the autocommit off, have you done it already?

Comment: No i didn't do it actually. But can you tell me what this will do. I am committing for each 25000 records.

Comment: Oracle make us commit our transactions as late as possible, but jdbc commits the work after every instruction (default behaviour, for many DBMS it makes sence). The class Connection has method setAutocommit you have to pass there the value false.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your support on this. It is really helpful to me.

Comment: @pardeep more detail is available at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29

Comment: If this operation is a maintenance operation (for example, an administrator or your application performs this operation once a day (night) or a week) you can use dedicated server processes and increase memory (PGA AREA, SORT AREA, HASH AREA and etc.) for the process that perform this operation. From here you have to work closely with your database administrator.

Comment: Thanks all for this support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute the `batch insert` inside a `transaction`. When executed inside a transaction you can make sure that either all updates are executed, or none are updated.Doing this you can just stop the database or the JDBC driver to impose a transaction boundary around each insertion step in the batch.

Do something like this

```
try{
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    // add to batch and execute batch
    connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
finally{
   //closing statements
   }
```